# What is wrong with my SMPS flyback circuit ?

Tags: circuit-diagram

I've made a 150w flyback circuit but it never worked and i can't figure out what is the mistake i have done

i have attached the schematic here 
most of it i got from the internet with some tweaks I've! done on it 
i added some resistors in parallel or series to get certain values since i was building this circuit completely from my junkbox

input = 220v 50hz output(should be) = 30v 5amp
frequency = around 80khz

transformer is an EI40 core with an airgap of 0.33m 
the primary side is 15turns in 2 halfs first one is 8 turns then the secondery side is 6 turns , aux is 3 turns , then finally the last 7 turns of primary (the dot here means the beginning of the winding and the output side dot is reveresed but that's the closest library i could find)

IC2 IS A TL431

[Schematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oe6O.png)

first test run output was zero 
i started checking out components i found the mosfet dead all leads are shorted
also the auxulary winding diode mur160 was shorted 
having a closer look i found the UC3842 pin 7 and 8 traces joined togther by a tiny copper and i cleared that

replaced the mosfet diode and UC3842 to be safe made another test and nope still no output this time the mosfet didn't die i can see 12V at the 3842 vcc which didn't appear before and pin 8 output is a few hundred mili volts

i suspect the MUR160 diodes are too slow for this circuit is that correct ?
what else should i look for ?
i can't really figure out what is wrong or why is it not outputting anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked! , i changed the UC3842 with a 3843 IC and it worked perfectly , i think the aux winding was not supplying enough voltage to start the 3842 but the 3843 works on a lower voltage.